# PHP - gc.maxlifetime and perfomance?

Tags: php, performance, session, garbage-collection

I would like to know if a higher gc.maxlifetime value will affect performance of site? Let's say 2 weeks (1209600 seconds).

The reason i'm asking is because some of my pages is taking minutes to load that were very fast before. I changed the value from the default 24 minutes to 2 weeks so that users' session data and login would be persistent. This was about 2 weeks ago which leads me to believe that the high gc.maxlifetime could be the problem for the slow pageload. It's not always the same pages though.

PS: I am in the process of moving to a cookie-based persistent login system which I believe is more performance friendly?

Thanks

Comment: It has low possibility this setting makes your page loading down. Has your site db interaction? It may be about db. Other side, when you lower your gc_lifetime, the page loading goes faster?

Comment: Yes it has db. The table being queried has about 13 000 rows which the user retrieves about 10 rows max at a time using LIMIT clause. The table is properly constructed, i think, using a JOIN. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should try to gc.maxlifetime setting. In general the garbage collector is a very lightweight process. I think you should try to find out why the page is slow. You could do this by adding timers between certain sets of code. Then see which part of your code is slow.

For example:

```
<?php

$start = microtime( true );
/* code block A */
$blockA = microtime( true ) - $start;

$start = microtime( true );
/* code block B */
$blockB = microtime( true ) - $start;


// etc.


/**
 * At the end of your script, you can use the times and 
 * print them to the screen, or log them to a file.
 */
echo '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Block A took '. round( $blockA, 2) .' seconds ' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Block B took '. round( $blockB, 2) .' seconds ' . PHP_EOL;
echo '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Good luck finding the slow parts. TIP: Take an extra look to your database queries, if there are any.

Comment: This sounds like the easiest and most logical way to start identifying the problem. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

`gc.max_lifetime` should not *directly* impact performance because all it does is set the duration after which sessions are fair game to delete (although there's no guarantee when it will end up being deleted actually).

There could be some collateral performance difference in that whenever the session GC kicks in it will have a larger number of sessions to examine for eligibility to clean up so it will take more time to sort all of them out. That is because you have increased the minimum lifetime of sessions, so all other things being equal at any one time there are more sessions underway than before.

There's a very simple check that you can make: have a look at the session storage mechanism (by default this means files in your system's temp directory) and see how many sessions currently exist. If it's filesystem sessions then there shouldn't be any visible performance degradation unless you have 10K or more; in any case, "visible performance degradation" would never climb into the minutes range (it's a hard disk, how slow can it be?).

Answer (score 1):

First there isn't an option "gc.maxlifetime" - what you mean is "session.gc_maxlifetime" ;)

The option "session.gc_maxlifetime" defines how long session data will not be deleted by the garbage collection (gc) process. The gc process will be started as often as defined with "session.gc_divisor" & "session.gc_probability".

if you have issues with it you should take a look where your session data will be stored (session save handler). Than you should optimize that process or disable it and clean the data by your self (cron).

If you use the default configuration PHP stores the session data on local hard disk and thats most often the bottleneck.

Increasing the value of "session.gc_maxlifetime" so much opens security issues and simply procrastinates your issue.